# What is the purpose of the LESS lib-css mixin?

Tags: magento2, frontend, less-css

The `.lib-css()` mixin is used heavily in Magento 2 LESS files. However its purpose is not apparent, and the mixin definitions don't provide any helpful documentation:

```
//
//  Add any css property
//  ---------------------------------------------

.lib-css(
    @_property,
    @_value,
    @_prefix: 0
) when (@_prefix = 1)
  and not (@_value = '')
  and not (@_value = false)
  and not (extract(@_value, 1) = false)
  and not (extract(@_value, 2) = false)
  and not (extract(@_value, 3) = false)
  and not (extract(@_value, 4) = false)
  and not (extract(@_value, 5) = false) {
  -webkit-@{_property}: @_value;
       -moz-@{_property}: @_value;
        -ms-@{_property}: @_value;
}

.lib-css(
    @_property,
    @_value,
    @_prefix: 0
) when not (@_value = '')
  and not (@_value = false)
  and not (extract(@_value, 1) = false)
  and not (extract(@_value, 2) = false)
  and not (extract(@_value, 3) = false)
  and not (extract(@_value, 4) = false)
  and not (extract(@_value, 5) = false) {
    @{_property}: @_value;
}
```

I could see why you would want to use the mixin to add vendor prefixes to bleeding edge CSS properties (although there are few properties where that is necessary any more), but the reason for outputting normal CSS properties using this mixin is not clear. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing, within Magento's code it seems to be inconsistent. For example where background is declared with a variable sometimes they use .lib-css and sometimes they don't, even within the same file.

Comment: My conspiracy theory on this one is that some of the developers at Magento wanted to have a utility less function that could be used in place of default less. This was more of a 'way of coding less' then a needed too for a specific purpose. But i would love to hear what other people might think about this.

Comment: autoprefixer wasn't cool enought?

Comment: Magento 2 style framework really is absolutely terrible. An annoying effect of this mixin is when inspecting styles using browser devtools, often instead of pointing to where the style was actually declared it points to the '.lib-css' mixin in _utilities.less. Cheers Magento  Does anyone know a way around this other than searching the codebase manually? M2 theme development is extremely frustrating.

Comment: @00-BBB agree with your final thought! Everything about M2 is an order of magnitude more overengineered that it was for M1 - and that was bad enough. LESS just adds another level of complication that detracts from what we should be doing - building a commerce site.

Answer (score 14):

The only uses I can see are the prefixes and removing previously declared rules:

### Prefixes

```
body {
    .lib-css(transition, color .5s ease, @_prefix: 1);
}
```

Will output:

```
body {
    webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: color 0.5s ease;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
```

### Removing previously declared rules instead of unsetting them

`.lib-css()` gives the ability to remove every rule that uses a certain variable instead of unsetting them or setting them to `0` or `none`. For example lets say we want to remove every rule that uses `@button__shadow`. Such as:

```
.product-list button {
    .lib-css(box-shadow, @button__shadow);
}
```

If it was only for one element it would be easier to write `box-shadow: none;`. But if this is on say 20 elements, it will be quicker to remove them all like so:

```
@button__shadow: false;
```

This has the added benefit of using `@variable: none` as it reduces lines of code, instead of adding more.

So compare these two methods:

**LESS**

Method 1:

```
.product-list button {
    .lib-css(box-shadow, @button__shadow);
}
```

Method 2:

```
.product-list button {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Or alternatively

```
@button__shadow: 0;
```

**Output**

[image: Magento 2 Less]

**LESS**

```
@button__shadow: false;

.product-list button {
    .lib-css(box-shadow, @button__shadow);
}
```

**Output**

*There is no output, the rules aren't processed*

This does seem like a good idea but the use cases seem pretty small. I'll more likely just use it for the prefixes. It would be much more useful if `@variable: false` could be set locally, for example only within one div, unfortunately I couldn't get this working.

#### Core usage

I've noticed some variables are set to false by default, such as ones in `lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_buttons.less`, I presume this is so they aren't outputted until required. Also a good idea.

```
//  Default = secondary button
@button__color: @primary__color;
@button__background: @color-gray95;
@button__border: 1px solid @color-gray-darken2;
@button__gradient-color-start: false;
@button__gradient-color-end: false;
```

Comment: And how do I know when I need to use `@_prefix: 1` ? I guess only on very new features? How do I know

Comment: This site comes in useful for that - http://shouldiprefix.com/

Comment: This feels like one of the best things I've read in a long time... the ability to remove a declaration with .lib-css and setting the property to `false` is invaluable!  I'm sick of CSS files growing via extending.  But this allows for an extend to modify the original - genius!!!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The **.lib-css() mixin** is used to set any css property if there is a value passed to it by a variable.
(e.g.)

```
[![.class {
    .lib-css(border-radius, @button__border-radius);
    .lib-css(border, @button-primary__border);
    .lib-css(color, @button-primary__color);
    .lib-css(background, @color-gray94);
    .lib-css(padding, @indent__s);
}
```

[image]

Also **.lib-css()** can add ***-ms-, -webkit- and -moz-*** prefixes if needed.

If the variable is set to ***false***, the ***.lib-css() mixin*** will add nothing to the code.

please review .lib-css variables

[image]

also you can find all less help under

```
<magento install directory>\lib\web\css\docs\utilities.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's still not clear why this: 
`.lib-css(border-radius, @button__border-radius);` 
would be any better than: 
`border-radius: @button__border-radius;`

Comment: also you can directly write CSS Property and value like this
.lib-css(border-radius, 5px);

Comment: This is literally the dumbest mixin of _all time_. Only the third parameter offers some value: "If set to "1" adds -ms-, -webkit- and -moz- prefixes to the property
"

Comment: Helpful answer. +1